# passing parameter in Javascript function in object

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

```
{
    label: 'Field Label',
    key: 'field-key',
    operation: somefunctionWithParam(param)   
}
```

and function

```
const = somefunctionWithParam(val) => {
    return format(val)
}
```

Operation function gets called from somewhere and it passes the value back. I need to pass a parameter from

```
somefunctionWithParam(param)
```

and access it from where I call it so that value can be manipulated based on parameter.

Comment: Use Fat-Arrow  `operation: () => somefunctionWithParam(param) ` or anonymous function

Comment: `const = somefunctionWithParam(val)` is a syntax issue, you need a variable name. as for your issue, you can just do `myVar = someFunctionWithParam(param);`

Answer (score 0):

> Operation function gets called from somewhere and it passes the value back

This happens because you are invoking the function while assigning it to the key `operation`.

Change your code to

```
const somefunctionWithParam = (val) => {
    return format(val)
}
```

and you can assign the function to the key `operation` like this

```
const obj = {
    label: 'Field Label',
    key: 'field-key',
    operation: somefunctionWithParam   
}
```

Or you can define an anonymous function like this

```
const obj = {
  label: 'Field Label',
  key: 'field-key',
  operation: (val) => {
      return format(val)
    }
}
```

Comment: `somefunctionWithParam = (val)` wants to be `function somefunctionWithParam(val)`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, I want to access param where I'm invoking the function from.

Comment: @JS-JMS-WEB can you clarify? do you mean you want to access the return value  from the function?

Comment: 'somefunctionWithParam' is a function with argument, I want to access it when it gets invoked.

Comment: @JS-JMS-WEB what do you mean by _"I want to access it when it gets invoked"_? Could you pl elaborate?

Comment: @JS-JMS-WEB so you want to access the value that is returned from the `someFunctionWithParam` function?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon added clarification, I want to access 'how-to-access-this-value' when function gets invoked . Thanks

Comment: @JS-JMS-WEB but what is `how-to-access-this-value`? do you mean `return format(val)`?